# Do I need additional drivers?

Tags: wireless, drivers, sound, ati, amd-processor

I've Dell Inspiron 15R 5520 laptop. Do I need to install additional drivers for it? If yes, how do I install additional drivers?

<sub>Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000

AMD Radeon Driver

Sound Devices: Conexant SmartAudio HD, Intel(R) Display Audio

USB Controllers: Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family

USB Enhanced Host   Controller - 1E26 Intel(R) 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family

USB Enhanced Host Controller - 1E2D Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller</sub>

Please guide me through this.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need Drivers?

To run hardware you need drivers.

> If yes where do I get drivers from?

The installer will pick all the drivers it can pick that your hardware supplies. So as long as the hardware is supported you yourself do not need to worry about drivers. Contrary to Windows Linux uses generic drivers; so we have 1 driver to rule lots of similar hardware (1 for NICs, 1 for nVidia, 1 for AMD, 1 for USB etc etc).

There might be 3rd party drivers but that is no need to install those. The 2 that are added to addition drivers are for videocards and some networdcards (from Broadcom). You can add those by search for "additional drivers" in dash.